# Foodsavers/dumpsters community in France?

Tags: france, food-and-drink

In Germany, and possibly other countries, there is an evolving food saver community with many local hubs where you can get food for free saving it from being wasted.

In France they have also a law which prohibits wasting food.

Is there anything similar to the mentioned food sharing hub network in France?

Comment: I don't know what you are refering to in Germany, but I have heard of *Too Good To Go*. Wikipedia claims they are active worldwide, which includes France

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, in France there are laws that prohibit supermarkets (but not restaurants, AFAIK) to throw away edible food (or worse : make it unsafe to eat after dumping i.e. by pouring bleach on it).

Instead, they are supposed to donate the surplus/(nearly-)expired food to welfare organisations such as Les Restos du Cœur (https://www.restosducoeur.org/), one of the banques alimentaires (https://www.banquealimentaire.org/), or other similar associations (Caritas/Secours Catholique, etc.).

So since there isn’t any food in dumpsters, there’s no dumpster community either (… that I’ve heard about).

Too Good to Go also operates in France (https://toogoodtogo.fr/fr) and seems successful enough to be known in most big cities.

Comment: thx - interestingly, in Germany the welfare organizations do not take everything (imagine 1 bad organge in a net) so the foodsavers have still a lot do, coming after the welfate people.